# How to Animate Multiple Background images?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a background made with 3 separate images i want to add rotate animation to all 3 images. If i animate the `number-bg` class all 3 images rotates. I want the rotate speed to be different for each image. what is the best approach to do that.

mycode

```
<style>
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .number-bg {
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/BZrswvf.png),
      url(https://i.imgur.com/XJ9zZeA.png),
      url(https://i.imgur.com/RJDk9uS.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="number-bg">
  </div>
</body>
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: why not split the images into three different elements?

Comment: to animate elements differently they must be different elements. You can start by this

Comment: yes i did not think of that before, having all images in different elements works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code to rotate each image at different speeds.

```css
.number{height: 1000px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;}

.no-9 {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/BZrswvf.png);
  
    -webkit-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 3s linear infinite
  }

.no-6 {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/XJ9zZeA.png);
  
    -webkit-animation:spin 6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 6s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 6s linear infinite
  }

.no-3 {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/RJDk9uS.png);
  
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite
  }

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
  <div class="number no-9">
    <div class="number no-6">
        <div class="number no-3"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Change the spin speeds as per your wish.